# Can all cases of tstring be replaced with wstring

Tags: c++, winapi

For example, I am updating an old project and I am wondering can I CTRL+H and replace all tstring with wstring? Is this ok? Thanks.

Comment: off-topic, but why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tstring is just a typedef based upon whether the build is unicode or not. It will translate to  wstring if the build unicode or simple string if it is not. So if your build will always be unicode then you can replace all the instances of tstring with wstring.

Comment: I don't see a `tstring` typedef or define in the Win SDK or MSVC headers - am I missing something?

Comment: It is actually a std::tstring class defined as below. I actually don't know where it is 
namespace std
{
    #ifdef _UNICODE 
        typedef wstring tstring;
    #else
        typedef string tstring;
    #endif
};